# Comparing class types does not work

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

When I debug my code this condition is true, but this block don't execute.
`if ([currentParameter class] == [TKTextFeedbackParameter class]) {...}`

This block execute if i pass any object (For example, `@(1)`).

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
TKFeedbackParameter *currentParameter = self.data[indexPath.section].parameters[indexPath.row];

if ([currentParameter isKindOfClass: [TKTextFeedbackParameter class]]) {...}
```

TKTextFeedbackParameter is child of TKFeedbackParameter

Comment: Your block does execute when you pass any object as `currentParameter` but not when you pass a `TKTextFeedbackParameter` type? Can you show more of the code?

Comment: i can pass (true == true) and this block never execute

Comment: You need to show more context. Update your question with a bit more code.

Comment: Show the full code. There must be something else wrong. Probably something within the block.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ([currentParameter isKindOfClass: [TKTextFeedbackParameter class]]) {...}
```

Although I do not see why your code should not work. The difference is that your code does an exact class comparison while `isKindOfClass` returns `yes` for all subclasses too.

Comment: It will be the same result

Comment: Then debug the line and have a look of which class currentParameter really is.

Comment: po [currentParameter class]
-> 
<TKTextFeedbackParameter>